# prevent flex element from expanding out of container

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/g8u43Lzx/1/).

- Pink is the dimension of the flex-container.
- flex element `class="fxel fxel2"` is exanding out of the container because its very "tall".

All solutions i've seen make some sort of "assumption" to the individual height of elements (in `px` or `%`).

#### Restrictions

- the height of `class="fxel fxel1"` varies at runtime. So no assumption regarding the height can be made.

#### Desired solution:

- `class="fxel fxel2"` should take all of the remaining height left in the pink.
- when the content is to "tall" it should start a `overflow: scroll` INSIDE  `<div class="fxel fxel2">` (this means the elements div has a scrollbar we dont "overflow" the window/body/html)

Any suggestions?

#### This here is some static bullshit placeholder of what im aiming for in a dynamic way:

[JSFIDDLE_SOLUTION_LOOKALIKE](https://jsfiddle.net/qxcma4j5/)

Comment: min-height:0 to your element, then you add overflow to them

Comment: thank you `.fxel2 {
  min-height: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}` gets me there! Thank you sir.

Comment: would you like to answer and loose a word of why and how `min-height: 0` solves this?

Comment: everything is already explained in the duplicate ;)

Comment: `.fxel2 {
  min-height: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}` is better. Sorry for asking a dupe :*(

Comment: maybe someone can use this dupe to find the right solution.

Comment: yes, dupe are made for this purpose, attract search to the canonical Q/A